# How to store Secrets on docker-compose.yaml as variables

Tags: linux, security, docker, cryptography, docker-compose

Is it possible to store secret variables as environment variables in linux and store them in hashed format and how to call them in docker-compose.yaml file. What are the best practice in storing secrets.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.